# while loop evalutaing to true when it is false C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, boolean, logical-operators

I've checked a couple of "Questions that may already have your answer" and still haven't found anything that has worked. My problem is a simple while loop that when evaluated to true, it loops and asks for user input, I enter in a number that should evaluate the while loop to false and exit, but it repeats. The second time I enter in the number. I am fairly new to C++, but I am assuming something is getting jacked up in my iostream.

1) I enter in "0", it evaluates the while loop to true and asks for the user input again as it is < 1.
2) When prompted again I enter in 1, which is obviously not < 1, the loop repeats again telling me "Invalid number -- the number must be bwtween " 
3) If I enter in 1 again....the while loop evaluates to false and moves on as it should have in step 2.

Code:

```
string question = "Enter number of days rented (1-365): ";

int getValidNumber(int num, int lowerNum, int upperNum, string question){

    while((num < 1) || (num > 365)) {

           cout << endl;
           cout << "Invalid number -- the number must be bwtween " <<
                   lowerNum << " and " << upperNum << "." << endl <<
                   "Please try again." << endl;
           cout << question;
           cin >> num;         
           }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `num`, or stepping through this code and observing the value of `num` after you enter it?

Comment: it case it wasn't obvious, how you are reading your initial number is pretty darn important here. Put the number in the error message so you can see what it was and thus why it keeps failing. You may be surprised.

Comment: After stepping through my problem....I found out what was happening. I was referencing to the function twcie....idiot. lol

Comment: This is basically a "please fix my code for me" question. do you know what is a debugger?

Comment: I was using a debugger...obviously it wasn't a very good one since it didnt inform me that I was calling the same function twice...did you read my comment above yours? Why are there so many trolls? If this guy downvoted me can any mods reverse it? this guy obviously was just having a bad day...how was it a "fix my code" question if I was trying to resolve an issue....anyway....isn't that the point of this site? lol freakin trolls. this was from 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at my code again, I was calling the same function twice. Operator error. That would do it....

```
cin >> rentalDays;
// Validate user input

getValidNumber(rentalDays, RENTAL_DAYS_MIN, RENTAL_DAYS_MAX, RENTAL_DAYS);
rentalDays = getValidNumber(rentalDays, RENTAL_DAYS_MIN, RENTAL_DAYS_MAX, RENTAL_DAYS);
```